# how do i create a delay between tap gestures in XNA on wp7

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

i am developing a mobile game using XNA and have an on and off switch which changes the state whenever tapped on. My problem is that it changes rapidly and multiple times from a single tap. How do i stop this?

Answer (score 2):

Store a time the in-game switch was last used and calculate the timespan passed

```
if(buttonPressed && (Datetime.Now - timeLastInGameSwitchActivated).Milliseconds > 1000)
{
    ToggleIngameSwitch();
    timeLastInGameSwitchActivated = Datetime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add a previous value variable to check the last state of the button, if its different to the current one then do the desired code
    ButtonState prev = state

```
if(currentstate != prev)
{
dothis
}
```

Comment: i tried delaying the game's update frequency, with no luck. if the current state and the previous state have to be different in order to turn the switch on wont this stop the user from turning the switch back off

Comment: its changing multiple times because of the 30 fps that wp7 has.. (you could ask your users to be very speedy with their clicks :p return joke;) You need some way of storing a state that stops your code being executed as it is already being executed

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple technique to deal with 'delay' stuff.

```
float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
timeCounter += elapsed;

if (timeCounter > yourMinimumDelayTime)
{
   //your code here
   timeCounter = 0;                     
}
```